# При INSERT в цикле происходит вставка только последнего элемента

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь в цикле занести информацию в базу mysql:

```
$jsonurl = "https://iextrading.com/api/1.0/stock/market/collection/list?collectionName=in-focus";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$get_data = json_decode($json,true);

$size_array = (count($get_data));
for ($i = 0; $i < $size_array; $i++) {
    $companyName = $get_data[$i]['companyName'];
    $latestPrice = $get_data[$i]['latestPrice'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (`company`,`price`) VALUES ('$companyName','$latestPrice')";
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo mysqli_error($link);
```

Данные добавляются, но только последнее значение (получается, они перезаписываются). А мне надо получить все данные по акциям. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Лучше вставку делайте батчем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query` внутрь цикла внесите:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size_array; $i++) {
    $companyName = $get_data[$i]['companyName'];
    $latestPrice = $get_data[$i]['latestPrice'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (`company`,`price`) VALUES ('$companyName','$latestPrice')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

И да, вставку лучше одним запросом батчить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Все работает!

Comment: Или выполнить перед циклом один раз prepare этого запроса с `values(?,?)`, в внутри цикла делать bind_param и execute. Что не сильно хуже по скорости чем групповые вставки и главное, исключает ошибки из за кавычек в данных

Comment: Обязательно все учту.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ.

```
$get_data = json_decode($json,true);

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (`company`,`price`) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $companyName, $latestPrice);

foreach ($get_data as $row) {
    $companyName = $row['companyName'];
    $latestPrice = $row['latestPrice'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Вы так говорите, будто мой ответ не правильный (: